# Updating an HTML page to Wordpress--Can I keep the old process?

Tags: php, wordpress

I really hope I can explain this clearly--I have experience in HTML/CSS but very little in PHP, but i'm learning.

Right now, i'm redesigning my job's (law research firm) website from a early 2000's html boxframe monster to a sleek, minimalist (>.>) wordpress site. All of the front-end stuff is done and perfect, but i'm having some trouble migrating a key process into the wordpress site.

Our clients access the website via a private link, which displays a page that includes links to the custom research we've done for them. There is a template for this page in the root folder, but the client is their project's folder, which includes the research, an index.php file and a copy of the template (pdf_report.php) I referenced earlier, edited for their custom project.

Now that I have created the wordpress page, and though the page looks similar, i'm seeing the back-end's changed quite a lot. What I need, specifically, is a starting point to help me link that project folder to the new wordpress version of that page. I should add that the project folders are contained within a folder within the root directory.

Is it possible to maintain the same system and have a pdf_report.php page in each folder? Or is there another way to approach this problem. Please let me know if you need more information on this. Right now, I have no clue where to start.

Comment: You can do that either using Theme workaround or using plugin

To start learning theme development:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Plugin development:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm working on a plugin, now!

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the Theme Development codex? You're for sure going to need to change file structures and things of that nature. It won't be as easy as injecting PHP into your existing HTML files.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development